# Angular Material Nested Tree

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can someone please help me with the simplest method of adding a new node to the angular material nested tree?
I searched everywhere and did not find a suitable method for the nested tree.
This is my cod so far :

```
TS:
export class FileNode {
  children!: FileNode[];
  fileName!: string;
  type: any;
}

    export class AppComponent {
      nestedDataSource= new MatTreeNestedDataSource<FileNode>();
      nestedTreeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FileNode>(node => node.children);
    
      constructor() {
        this.nestedDataSource.data=TREE_DATA;
       }
    
       hasChild = (nr: number, nodeData: FileNode) => { return !(nodeData.type); };
          } 
HTML :
<mat-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl" class="example-tree">

<!--The node who does not need expansion because is a file of a folder-->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
      <li class="mat-tree-node">
          <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
          {{node.fileName}}: {{node.type}}
          <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
      </li>
  </mat-tree-node>

<!--The node who does need expansion because is a folder-->
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
      <li>
          <div class="mat-tree-node">
              <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle>
                  <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                      {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                  </mat-icon>
              </button>
              {{node.fileName}}
              <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
          </div>
          <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
              <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>

<!--The compiler chooses the node depending on the method: hasNestedChild-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for is already available in their official documentation. Please check the https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples#tree-checklist link and let me know if it doesn't solve your use case.

Comment: Yes, I know about that documentation, but I thought it was an easier method without checkboxes and other additions (a bit more common at first). In that documentation, even the creation of the tree is more complicated than mine. I mean the documentation contains both flat and nested tree and other things